# Helpful answer typo

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling, unicoins

The "helpful" answer includes the text

> If you then combine **the all the** small solutions

Comment: [[meta-tag:status-deferred]] 'till tomorrow.

Comment: ...or not @balpha.